# Are moderators able to move comment threads to chat?

Tags: support, moderation, chat, comments

### Moving Multiple Threads to Site Chat Room

Our own [help center](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) says:

> Comments are not recommended for...[s]econdary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead[.]

[This question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/12758/4271) currently has two ridiculously-long comment threads attached to the following answers:

- https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/12771/4271
- https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/12761/4271

These threads exceed the reasonable bounds of what should be in a comment (e.g. simple clarifications of a post) and should be moved to chat. It would probably be useful to have the threads moved to [The PMSE Notice Board](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/380/the-pmse-notice-board), but that would appear to require moderator privileges.

If there's value in community involvement in this particular discussion, I feel like it should be moved to the community chat room. As I understand it, the pop-up asking me if I want to move long threads to chat instead creates a private chat room between the current participants, which seems less useful.

I don't really mind the content of the messages staying where they are per se, but they seem to violate our help center guidelines and add needless clutter to the page. In addition, the content of the threads seems like a secondary discussion that doesn't materially add to the Q&A content of the original posts. Is it possible to have someone with elevated privileges move the threads *en masse* to the site chat room?

Comment: @jmort253 You're pretty active on The Workplace, where I notice the Moderator Hammer comes down fairly often on comment threads. I'd appreciate your take on how appropriate that is to PMSE.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think either of these are "ridiculously long" and one of them is a direct result of you refusing to clarify a point in your answer.

This feels like an attempt to remove some comments which directly refute your answer by using primary source material.

Also, the comments add genuine real world context to any users arriving via Google Search.  In the context of the question I think both sets of comments; even those that disagree with me are extremely useful for potential answer-seekers.